Postgres settings to maximize compute resources for a single local connection
I have a local PG instance populated with 10's of millions of rows of data and need to run some relatively complex queries for some data analysis work.
These queries are currently taking 10+ minutes to return (even after adding custom index's for every query I'm running).
While this may not be the "right tool for the job", I'm sure that my system isn't fully utilizing its available resources. I've configured my system using PGTune, but it still seems like this is taking into account a margin of safety for application stability, multiple connections, competing processes, etc.
If I just want PG to run as fast as it possibly can for my single connection...
What are the most important settings? And how should they be configured, relative to the system specs?
(Mine are 8-core, 32GB ram for example)

Disagree with the close reason.
PG falls well into "software tools primarily used by programmers."

Right. The correct close reason is that you provided too little information.

"margin of safety for application stability" - if you're willing to sacrifice that, you can consider non-durable settings. Make sure you have a cold backup to go back to and take a look at the rest of performance tips and resource consumption settings.

The manual lists EXPLAIN first for a reason - even a very slight improvement to your schema and the queries in your pipeline can yield disproportionately better results (orders of magnitude) than multiplying your resources, lifting all resource consumption constraints and removing all safety measures. One advantage of those last 3 things is you don't have to read any of the code you're trying to speed up - which might be preferable when dealing with a ton of legacy code to go through. Still, even then, removing just a few most obvious bottlenecks might outweigh all config tweaks.

Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your slow SQL statement, the statement itself and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? All in plain text, as an update of your question. And for your information, there is no configuration setting "maximize compute resources for a single connection". The best config depends on your hardware, usage pattern and configuration.

@LaurenzAlbe What information is lacking?  I explained exactly what I was trying to do, what I had tried, and supporting information that I thought was sufficient to help provide an answer.  The question and answers provided so far would be useful to anyone in the same shoes.
You're doing the thing that makes StackOverflow feel toxic at times...

I am sorry if my comment sounded nasty. There is a dedicated Stackexchange forum for DBA questions. Computer screens are also tools used by programmers, still questions about them would be off-topic here. As a programmer, you should understand that the question "I have some complex queries, which parameters should I set to make them faster" is too vague.

@LaurenzAlbe ty, I was a lot not aware of the DBA stack exchange.  Before posting, I read at least 5 similar questions in SO about pg performance tuning.
Seems like a transfer would have been appropriate, but instead this was flagged as "off-topic" within 30s and with no comment.   I've been a part of this community for a long time, and wasn't trying to add another "do my homework for me" question.   This Q seemed like a legit gap and honestly was only partially answered.  Someone will end up here one day and be disappointed to not have a high quality answer it might have gotten otherwise.

Your question is certainly not a homework question. But it is impossible to answer a question like "something is slow, but I won't bother to tell you more details". If you had posted a slow query and its execution plan, you could have received more than some vague ideas. You overestimate the importance of database parameters.

@LaurenzAlbe I'm swapping out 10's of millions of records with complexly different data structures (table is just a JSONB column + id and type fields) and only need to run each query a single time.  I know my DB and queries are not optimized, but my CPU and RAM aren't even breaking a sweat as queries take 10s of minutes to return.
The question I posted is not "How do I optimize this query".  It's how do I get Postgres to consume all of my machine's available resources.  If there are bottlenecks that make that impossible, then that an even more interesting potential answer.

The default for max_parallel_workers_per_gather is 2, which is too low for the situation you describe.  It should be set equal to the number of CPUs (actually one less than the number of CPUs, but that isn't likely to make any meaningful difference).  But not all queries can benefit from parallel workers, so this might not make much difference to you.
High values for effective_io_concurrency can help if your queries involve bitmap heap scans and if your IO system can benefit from having multiple IO requests in flight at the same time (RAID/JBOD generally can.  SSD (even single-drive systems) usually can if it is high quality. Even single-disk HDD can often get some smallish benefit).
Setting effective_cache_size to the same size as all of RAM (or just slightly less) can help for some queries.
Increasing work_mem can help.  But be careful not to overdue, even a single session can allocate many multiples of work_mem if it involves sorts in many different executor nodes, or parallel workers, or partitions.  Although the "spill to disk" algorithms are now so good that this often doesn't make a big difference.

This comes the closest to answering the question as asked (How do I squeeze max performance out of my resources)... Although after tweaking things and maxing stuff out, it's clear that really only takes you so far and there is no escaping query optimization.

If your statements are slow, you have to find the cause with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) and improve that. Twiddling parameters will achieve less than you think.
That said, the most important parameter for queries on big tables is work_mem. Set it as high as you can without going out of memory.
